Expected value involving CDF
Let $F$ be a cumulative distribution function with corresponding density $f(x)=F'(x)$. I am interested in the following integral:
\begin{equation}
    I = \int_a^b x F(x) f(x) dx,
\end{equation}
where $[a, b]$ is the support of $f$. A first approach would suggest setting $u=x, dv = F(x)f(x)dx$ and apply integration by parts:
\begin{equation}
    I
    = \int_a^b x F(x) f(x) dx
    =
    \left[\frac{xF(x)^2}{2}\right]_a^b
    - \int_a^b \frac{F(x)^2}{2} dx
    =
    \frac{b}{2}
    - \int_a^b \frac{F(x)^2}{2} dx,
\end{equation}
where we have used $F(a)=0, F(b)=1$. However, the first term might be problematic, since $b=\infty$ is a possibility. In fact, take an exponential distribution with parameter $1$, whose density has support $[0, \infty)$. In this case, $b=\infty$ so that the above approach would not work. Nonetheless, $I$ can be computed to be $3/4$, so the integral does converge.
Is there another approach that can provide an expression for $I$, perhaps through a more careful analysis? For instance, as $x\to b$ then $F(x)\to 1$ so that the integrand essentially corresponds to $x F(x) f(x) \approx x f(x)$ which could provide some way of controlling this quantity if we assume $f$ decays sufficiently rapidly. However, I am not sure how to formalize this best.

In your exponential distribution example, you could take $\lim\limits_{b \to \infty}\left( \frac{b}{2}   - \int\limits_0^b \frac{F(x)^2}{2} ,dx\right)$ and get the answer  $\lim\limits_{b \to \infty}\left( \frac{1}{4e^{2b}} -  \frac{1}{e^{b}} +\frac34\right) =\frac34$.  If for some other distribution you also had $a=-\infty$, you could turn that into a limit too.
